# Postgresql I/O utilization

Tags: postgresql, io, server, newrelic, utilization

Newrelic shows I/O pikes of up to 100% reads.

[image]

The rest of the time it's close to 0.

It doesn't coincide in time with our cron jobs (database backup, analyze, etc.), also almost no match with autovacuum (pg_stat_all_tables.last_autovacuum).

Querying pg_stat_activity also shows nothing but our simple queries sent by Ruby application

```
select * 
from pg_stat_activity 
where query_start between '2017-09-25 09:00:00' and '2017-09-25 11:00:00';
```

And these queries are not even among our slow queries in log file.

Please advise how to identify what processes cause such I/O load.

Comment: `pg_stat_activity` does not provide a history of past queries. Turn on statement logging and use [pgBadger](http://dalibo.github.io/pgbadger/) to analyze the log.

Comment: Are checkpoints happening during the spikes?